# Why do one of these two variables print in opposite order into the file?

Tags: c++, endianness

Here are the variables:

```
int z = 0x12345678;
char zz[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };
```

I print them into file using:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("myfile.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
myfile.write((const char*)&z, sizeof(z));
myfile.write((const char*)&zz, sizeof(zz));
myfile.close();
```

The file contains this when seen in hex editor:

```
78 56 34 12 12 34 56 78
```

Why does the order reverse? What is the workaround to make both behave same way? I would prefer that the int prints in the same order like I type it in as the char does.

I am having the same issue at another place, I wrote a function that prints binary for an input value. It takes parameter as const char*. I cast the int z'saddress as const char* and can call the function, I can pass address of zz as well. The function masks each bit and to see if it is 0 or 1 and prints it to the screen. Since the int and char are not interpreted the same way, the function works with char but not with int.

Comment: If your function doesn't work then it has assumed the endianness incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you are running your code on a little endian machine, hence the int is stored in memory as 78 - 56 - 34 -12. 
As you are writing the sequence of byte you are writing on disk the 4 bytes of the int as they are in memory. Hence the int has a specular rappresentation compared to the 4 bytes array.

The point is: until you write and read the same type of data on the same machine (so you are not dealing with Big Endian and Little Endian problem) I don't see the point of find a solution in order to have two 12345678 sequence written on disk.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of endianess (Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness ) . You should write endiness-independent code to avoid such issues.

Edit: IBM has a wonderful article on this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html